# Rails4: eager loading not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't understand when eager loading is sufficient and when it's not. I'll make a practical example:
take the models on the image below, I must get the teams that have played a certain match (so I need some joins):

In my **MatchesController** I do the following:

```
@matches = Match.scheduled_or_playing
.joins(match_locations: {scores: {team_match: :team}})
.includes(match_locations: {scores: {team_match: :team}})
```

and in my **index view** I do the following:

```
<% @matches.each do |m| %>
    <%= m.teams.map(&:name).join " | "  %> 
<% end
```

This triggers a lot of queries, as shown in this log:

```
  SQL (5.1ms)  SELECT "matches"."id" AS t0_r0, "matches"."server_id" AS t0_r1, "matches"."pool_id" AS t0_r2, "matches"."state" AS t0_r3, "matches"."can_draw" AS t0_r4, "matches"."scheduled_at" AS t0_r5, "matches"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "matches"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "match_locations"."id" AS t1_r0, "match_locations"."match_id" AS t1_r1, "match_locations"."location_id" AS t1_r2, "match_locations"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "match_locations"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "scores"."id" AS t2_r0, "scores"."match_location_id" AS t2_r1, "scores"."team_match_id" AS t2_r2, "scores"."points" AS t2_r3, "scores"."created_at" AS t2_r4, "scores"."updated_at" AS t2_r5, "team_matches"."id" AS t3_r0, "team_matches"."team_id" AS t3_r1, "team_matches"."created_at" AS t3_r2, "team_matches"."updated_at" AS t3_r3, "teams"."id" AS t4_r0, "teams"."encrypted_password" AS t4_r1, "teams"."remember_created_at" AS t4_r2, "teams"."sign_in_count" AS t4_r3, "teams"."current_sign_in_at" AS t4_r4, "teams"."last_sign_in_at" AS t4_r5, "teams"."current_sign_in_ip" AS t4_r6, "teams"."last_sign_in_ip" AS t4_r7, "teams"."ts_address" AS t4_r8, "teams"."ts_password" AS t4_r9, "teams"."picture_url" AS t4_r10, "teams"."name" AS t4_r11, "teams"."username" AS t4_r12, "teams"."created_at" AS t4_r13, "teams"."updated_at" AS t4_r14 FROM "matches" INNER JOIN "match_locations" ON "match_locations"."match_id" = "matches"."id" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "scores"."match_location_id" = "match_locations"."id" INNER JOIN "team_matches" ON "team_matches"."id" = "scores"."team_match_id" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "team_matches"."team_id" WHERE "matches"."state" IN (1, 2) ORDER BY matches.scheduled_at ASC
  Team Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "team_matches" ON "teams"."id" = "team_matches"."team_id" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "team_matches"."id" = "scores"."team_match_id" INNER JOIN "match_locations" ON "scores"."match_location_id" = "match_locations"."id" WHERE "match_locations"."match_id" = $1  [["match_id", 56]]
  Team Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "team_matches" ON "teams"."id" = "team_matches"."team_id" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "team_matches"."id" = "scores"."team_match_id" INNER JOIN "match_locations" ON "scores"."match_location_id" = "match_locations"."id" WHERE "match_locations"."match_id" = $1  [["match_id", 68]]

  ....(n times)

  Team Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" INNER JOIN "team_matches" ON "teams"."id" = "team_matches"."team_id" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "team_matches"."id" = "scores"."team_match_id" INNER JOIN "match_locations" ON "scores"."match_location_id" = "match_locations"."id" WHERE "match_locations"."match_id" = $1  [["match_id", 47]]
```

But, if i modify the **view** in this way...

```
<% @matches.each do |m| %>
    <%= m.teams  %> 
<% end %>
```

the view doesn't produce the same result, but it SHOULD load the same classes and attrs.
However, magically, now eager loading works, here's the log

```
 SQL (4.9ms)  SELECT "matches"."id" AS t0_r0, "matches"."server_id" AS t0_r1, "matches"."pool_id" AS t0_r2, "matches"."state" AS t0_r3, "matches"."can_draw" AS t0_r4, "matches"."scheduled_at" AS t0_r5, "matches"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "matches"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "match_locations"."id" AS t1_r0, "match_locations"."match_id" AS t1_r1, "match_locations"."location_id" AS t1_r2, "match_locations"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "match_locations"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "scores"."id" AS t2_r0, "scores"."match_location_id" AS t2_r1, "scores"."team_match_id" AS t2_r2, "scores"."points" AS t2_r3, "scores"."created_at" AS t2_r4, "scores"."updated_at" AS t2_r5, "team_matches"."id" AS t3_r0, "team_matches"."team_id" AS t3_r1, "team_matches"."created_at" AS t3_r2, "team_matches"."updated_at" AS t3_r3, "teams"."id" AS t4_r0, "teams"."encrypted_password" AS t4_r1, "teams"."remember_created_at" AS t4_r2, "teams"."sign_in_count" AS t4_r3, "teams"."current_sign_in_at" AS t4_r4, "teams"."last_sign_in_at" AS t4_r5, "teams"."current_sign_in_ip" AS t4_r6, "teams"."last_sign_in_ip" AS t4_r7, "teams"."ts_address" AS t4_r8, "teams"."ts_password" AS t4_r9, "teams"."picture_url" AS t4_r10, "teams"."name" AS t4_r11, "teams"."username" AS t4_r12, "teams"."created_at" AS t4_r13, "teams"."updated_at" AS t4_r14 FROM "matches" INNER JOIN "match_locations" ON "match_locations"."match_id" = "matches"."id" INNER JOIN "scores" ON "scores"."match_location_id" = "match_locations"."id" INNER JOIN "team_matches" ON "team_matches"."id" = "scores"."team_match_id" INNER JOIN "teams" ON "teams"."id" = "team_matches"."team_id" WHERE "matches"."state" IN (1, 2) ORDER BY matches.scheduled_at ASC
```

I really cannot understand why

EDIT:

as requested, I add the models here:

**Team**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :team_matches
  has_many :matches, :through => :team_matches
end
```

**TeamMatch**

```
class TeamMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :scores, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :team_match
  has_many :match_locations, through: :scores
end
```

**Score**

```
class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team_match
  belongs_to :match_location
end
```

**MatchLocation**

```
class MatchLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :match      
  has_many :scores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores
  has_many :team_matches, through: :scores
end
```

**Match**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :match_locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :match_locations, allow_destroy: true 
  has_many :scores, through: :match_locations
  has_many :team_matches, through: :scores
  has_many :teams, through: :team_matches
end
```

[image: models relations]

Comment: Could you show us what your `Match` and `Team` model look like in ActiveRecord? Do you have an association defined?

Comment: Here you are, edited with all involved models associations

Comment: Ok - now, the other confusion I have is that your view looks the same in both cases. Am I missing something? Are they for the same controller action?

Comment: They are the same controller action. Oh my god! there was a copy/paste mistake. now you have the 2 views :-). sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ActiveRecord is not recognizing the way you want eager loading `teams` through nested through associations. Try just including `teams` at the "match level" rather than nested.

```
@matches = Match.scheduled_or_playing
  .joins(:teams)
  .includes(:teams)
```

If you need all that other nested eager loading then simply include it back in:

```
@matches = Match.scheduled_or_playing
  .joins([:teams, {match_locations: {scores: {team_match: :team}}}])
  .includes([:teams, {match_locations: {scores: {team_match: :team}}}])
```

Check your logs to make sure the queries and eager loading are working as expected (including performance).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things to note here.

Firstly, you probably do not need to use `joins` and `includes` together. They are similar but not the same.

`includes` does an eager fetch, whereas `joins` does not. Note that in your case you have `joins` before `includes`. So the association is fetched using `join`.

Next, looking at your different views,

When you do a `m.teams`, you are only referring to the association, not the actual `teams` collection. However, in your first view when you do a `m.teams.map...` you are now referring the attributes of the association, which causes ActiveRecord to fetch the `Team` objects, as required (i.e. lazy). Hence the N+1 query problem.

Ryan Bates has an excellent [Rails Cast to compare this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins).

Comment: thank you i'm going to watch it. Any suggests for avoiding n+1 ?

Comment: When using `includes` without `joins` ActiveRecord will actually make one query for each association (or table???) it loads eagerly. By using `joins` together with `includes` ActiveRecord can perform all the loading/eager loading in one single query.

Comment: I removed the `joins` statement, but I still have the n+1 queries,
also putting my `joins` statement after the `include` statement has the same result

Comment: maybe I need to make some select explicitly?